# What is the shortkey for adding a space before a word in normal mode?

Tags: normal-mode, whitespace, vi-words

I have the following text:

```
#Text
```

My cursor is on character `T`; I want to obtain

```
# Text
```

i.e., to put a space between `#` and `T`, *without* "pressing `i` and then `space`". Instead, I want to do so in one single command *without* mapping. Is there any pre-defined shortkey for this?
Thanks

Comment: Why should it? If you believe you need it, then create a mapping of your own. If you say "I don't want a mapping" then don't.

Comment: @Matt I was wondering if there is a shortkey because it is fun and also beautiful to do the modifications this way. My inspiration for asking this question was the shortkey  `diw`; I was wondering if there is, something like `<space>iw`.

Comment: `diw` is not "a shortcut". It's "delete" applied to "inner word" text object. It's not so hard to create "prepend space" thing and to apply it to any existing text object, but (a) not everyone will find it useful, and so it's not in the core, (b) it'll be a mapping.

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I suppose your saying as the answer, so will accept it if you post.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!